# android- google map stop working

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

I've used google maps in my application since 8 month ago . I'm using eclipse. It works nice and every thing was ok. Now I find out that maps are not showing anymore , it shows the google icon and zoom icons too but it doesn't show the maps .

I went to new google developer console . https://console.developers.google.com and I enabled Google Maps Android API on the console , then I went to "credential" and regenerate a new key .

I change some codes in manifest , this is my manifest code :

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


<permission
    android:name="myapplication.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="ir.persiandesigners.jazebehayeiran2.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
<!-- end map -->

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="myApiKey" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

I export the app and installed it again but it doesn't work yet .

what should I do ? Why it is not working ?

by the way ,I'm having google play service lib verion 4.3.23 in the eclipse and I'm sure that I've installed google play service on my phone .

thanks

Comment: And what about the new package name?

Answer (score 1):

When you export the app did you use another key other than `debug.keystore`. Then you should generate the **SHA1 key** with the keystore file you used to export the app.

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" 
android:value="your_API_key"/>

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
 android:value="google_play_services_system_key"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
```

"google_play_services_system_key" this will you get in your error when you run your code. this is your system key put that here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Open your SDK manager and Update the `Google Play Services` and `Google Repository`.